# What is a good intervalometer with bracketing options for Sony a6000?

Tags: hdr, bracketing, sony-alpha

I've been on the a6000 for a few years, and bracketing for HDR has been the hardest part of the whole camera because of the silly limitations Sony keeps insisting on leaving in place. Things like having the 2-second delay on the same menu as the bracketing, or requiring that I actually hold the shutter button for the entire bracket set.

I've been using a TriggerTrap for a while, but I've found it to be very flaky. It's bound to the headphone plug of my phone, so I can't listen to music while out on a photo walk, and I have to set the phone to airplane mode to keep a rogue notification from spoiling a long exposure set.

Are there any recommendations for a hardware intervalometer for this camera that can do at least 5-shot bracketing with at least 1-stop exposure differences?

Comment: Most "dumb" intervalometers can be set to emulate a multiple-second shutter press.